# extract the coordinates of the points of a Survfit line

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

i hope the example will work.
i wanted to know if there is a way to extract the coordninates of EACH point  od a survival curve.
i know from `?plot.survfit`    that it will produce a values with the coordinates of the end of each class, but i would like to know all the points in which the line changes

```
library(survival)
status <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
classification <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8)
df <-data.frame( Sub = c(letters,LETTERS[1:24]), 
                         status= status, 
                         time= round(rnorm(50,300,100),0), 
                         class = classification )
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~class, data= df)
plotFit <- plot(fit)
```

i know i can extract the surv value from 
`fit$surv`, and that i can combine them with  the `fit$time` and `fit$n.event` but from this matrix i had to create a cycle to create a point at every 90 degree turn when a status changes, so was wandering if there was a faster way to have directly the values of all those line turning points.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think its survfit with lowercase and I guess the data.frame was constructed wrong. Like this, the code runs.

```
library(survival)
status <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
classification <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8)


df <-data.frame( Sub = c(letters,LETTERS[1:24]),
                 status= status,
                 time= round(rnorm(50,300,100),0), 
                 class = classification )

fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~class, data= df)
plotFit <- plot(fit)
```

For the coordinates, below is just a start. I think you have to split the lines at the n.events to plot it correctly.

```
x <- c(1,fit$time)
y <- c(1,(fit$surv))
plot(x,y, type="S")
```

You could also check out the package `survminer` and check out the function `ggsurvplot`. The plots are nicer and the plot-function is exported. Maybe that will help?

```
library(survminer)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = df)
ggsurvplot
```

Comment: thanks for the corrections to the code, I don't need the actual plot, but the coordinates for other calculations, and  i made a matrix for each rank, with fit$time,fit$n.event , fit$surviva, i think i have to make a cycle to  see when the event changes and take it s Time coordinate twice with different y ,but was wandering if there was a faster/more direct way  of extracting them from the function.

Comment: I know, it was just a start but I am not familiar with the survival package and the `plot.survfit` is not an exported function, so we cannot look into it. But from the help page of `plot.survfit` I think you also need to include `fit$strata` somehow. As it says: *one curve for each strata*

Comment: just for future reader, yes, unfortunately the strata changes the names of the suddivision you put, and list them as a table e.g. giving me class=1 3 class=2 7 so i actually added them  in a dataframe using the classification vector itself. thanks for the help anyway!